# Not more than one special symbol in a range from a long text

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Simplify the problem:

There is an article (long text)

Extract the content between `start` (included) and `end` (included)

Requirement: There cannot be more than one `\n` between `start` and `end`

Find all matches

Use `python` `re` only

For code:

```py
lines = re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    print('===')
```

So, how can I fixed my pattern?

What I try `pattern`:

1. `start[^\n]*\n?[^\n]*end`
   with text:

```
...
start just me and python regex 1 end
start just me and python regex 2 end
start just me and python regex 3 end
...
```

`wrong`:

```
start just me and python regex 1 end
start just me and python regex 2 end --> should be split with the line before
===
start just me and python regex 3 end
===
```

2. `start(?:(?!\n\n).)*?end` and `start(?:[^\n]|\n(?!\n))*?end`
   with text:

```
start just 
me and python 
regex 1 end
start just me and python regex 2 end
start just me and python regex 3 end
```

`wrong`:

```
start just 
me and python 
regex 1 end --> should not match this cause there is two `\n` in
===
start just me and python regex 2 end
===
start just me and python regex 3 end
===
```

Comment: `start[^\n]*\n?[^\n]*end` looks like it works as expected. Note that, when you ask for all matches at once, no matches will overlap. If you want overlapping matches, you'll need need to search for one match, set an start offset, search for another, set a further start offset, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use: `start[^\n]*?\n?[^\n]*?end`

Comment: The continuous `?` is a bit hard for me to understand, but it's right, Thanks

Comment: @Seven read the regex syntax, what do you mean with `continuous ?`

Comment: @Seven The extra `?` tell the preceding `*` to match shortest. Normally they match longest.

Comment: @Ouroborus if you explain it use the correct term: greedy and non-greedy quantifier